# How to set Default Directory which is selected after logging in to the new Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azureportal

For my Azure account there are 3 directories associated. After logging in *always* one of them is selected, so I have to switch to an other what I prefer after every login in the top right menu.

How can I change this default to my preference? 
I mean, after logging I would like to my preferred directory should be the selected without any repeated additional actions.

(If this can be donw with Azure PowerShell I am OK with that, the only requirement is it must affect my interactive logins to the new Azure Portal: My preferred directory should be the selected by default.

Comment: You can try setting the default AD from classic portal, check this article https://www.itunity.com/article/how-to-change-the-default-directory-for-an-existing-azure-subscription-2494  for details.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible at the minute.

Please vote up
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/6239996-choose-default-directory

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that question it is way not exact in its terminology, using the account term. After you logged in the "account" is determined, no way to choose or "set default". No such thing like "default account". The only thing you can do it by definition to log out and log in to an other account. Of course for one account the can be exist multiple subscriptions and directories. However terms "account", "subscription" and "directory" are not interchangable.....